# Adding a new array does not update my total array count in Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

**Problem:** *Initially my count is correct, however, adding a new array does not update my total array count label.*

I have a View Controller (**VC**) that shows a label with a count of total arrays. 
I have a Table View Controller (**TVC**) that arrays are added or deleted from. 
I have a separate struct file to hold the arrays.

The label populates with the correct number of arrays when I run it. However, adding a new array item (via **TVC**) in the simulator does not update the label on the **VC**.

Questions:

1. Should I put the count in a function in **VC**? It is currently in the viewDidLoad()
2. Should I then call the function in **TVC** when adding or deleting an array?
3. If 2 is yes then do I reference the function in **VTC**? Would it simply be
   `updateCount()` or do I have to reference the **VC** controller e.g.
   `ViewController.updateCount()`

I have tried both ways but it does not seem to work, if I can get confirmation that would be great then I can make it work.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: You have to update the label when you modify the array.  It only knows the value you give it at the time you give it.

Comment: How do I reference the label in the TVC (to update it) if it is in another controller(VC)? @clawesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is bad but it works.

The easiest answer is use static variable, but it will cost memory phone. example code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class VC: UIViewController {
    static var count = 0
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        label.text = String(VC.count)
    }
}

class TVC: UITableViewController {

    func updateCount() {
        VC.count = VC.count + 1
    }
}
```

Whenever function updateCount() called in TVC, and go back to VC class it will update the count.

My other suggestion is use MVVM pattern that sending VCViewModel as parameter to TVC. and update count in VCViewModel.

Other suggestion is use delegate pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this:

```
var x = 0
var y = x
x = 7
print(y) //y is still 0
```

You need to update the count whenever you change the amount of arrays. To call a view controller's function from another view controller, you need to use a protocol. I suggest you research how to make protocols in swift - I would help you but it's hard without being able to see the code.

Comment: Thank you, I had added code to print the value. The function that updates the arrays are in my Struct file. The function prints out the correct value, I just do not know how to reference my label that is not in the struct file as part of the struct function if this makes sense?

Comment: That's what I was taking about, you need to use something called a protocol and delegate. Basically, you make one view controller a "delegate" of the other, and then the second view controller can access the delegate and call its functions.